# animonscroll.js ajax loaded content not show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, masonry, onscroll

I am using animOnScroll plugin which uses masonry to do a scroll animation and load my data from ajax after it loaded. But after putting html content into grid container it will not show up. all div and li are not visible. How to reload grid container after putting dynamic content, How can I fix this?

here is my code.

```
//Animate on scroll
var offerGrid = new AnimOnScroll( document.getElementById( 'grid' ), {
    minDuration : 0.4,
    maxDuration : 0.7,
    viewportFactor : 0.2
});

// search offers
$('#load-offers-form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var postData = $(this).serialize();
    $.post(site_url+'/welcome/loadMoreOffers', postData, function(data) {
        $('#grid').html('');
        var content = genOfferHtml(data);
        $('#grid').html(content);
    });
});

// generate html from data
function genOfferHtml(data){
    var html = '';
    if (data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(data, function(i, offer) {
            if (i == 0) {
                html+='<li>';
            }else if(i % 2 == 0){
                html+='</li>\
                <li>';
            }
            html+='<div class="col-sm-6 offer">\
            <a href="">\
            <div class="overlay" style="background-image:url('+baseUrl+offer.offer_image_path+offer.offer_image+')">\
            <div class="offer-hotel">'+offer.hotel_name+'</div>\
            <div class="offer-hotel-location">'+offer.city_name+' ,'+offer.country_name+'</div>\
            <div class="offer-details col-sm-12">\
            <div class="col-sm-9 offer-dates-bg">\
            FROM '+offer.offer_startdate+' TO '+offer.offer_enddate+'\
            </div>\
            <div class="offer-val-bg col-sm-3 pull-right">\
            <div>'+offer.discount+'</div>\
            <div>OFF</div>\
            </div>\
            </div>\
            </div>\
            </a>\
            </div>';
        });         
    }else{
        html+='<li>no data</li>';   
    }
    return html;
}
```